# Overridable and Override in C# and VB

Tags: c#, .net, oop

In C#, `override` is enabled by default so, is there no need to *explicitly* declare a method as overridable in the base class? If so

1. Is Overridable just limited to VB.NET or it is required in C# as well?
2. Hence which type of methods can be overridden? Is it only abstract methods of an abstract class or any method?

Comment: A method marked as `virtual` can be overridden with the `override` keyword. An overriding method is still virtual (you don't repeat the `virtual` keyword, though) and can be overridden again. To stop the method from being further overridden, use the `sealed` keyword.

Comment: As others mentioned below, in C#, all abstract methods are virtual by default if prefixed by Abstract keyword. This means method signature is present only in the Abstract Class but the method implementation is written elsewhere?

Comment: Correct. Try it. First write a class and mark the class abstract. Then introduce an abstract method, for example `public abstract int GetNumber();` If you then write a non-abstract class that derives from the first class, the compiler will force you to provide an implementation of `GetNumber()`.

Comment: Can another abstract class inherit another abstract class?

Comment: Yes, certainly. And an abstract class can inherit a non-abstract class too.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `Overridable` keyword in VB corresponds to the `virtual` keyword in C#.

You have to make a method virtual to be able to override it. Abstract methods are automatically virtual.

Comment: Finally I want to know when to use an abstract class? I never felt a need to declare a class as Abstract so far. Why not write another method instead of overriding an existing?

Comment: @RPK: Abstract members are used when you create a base class that has a member that needs to be implemented by all classes that inherit the base class.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, any method marked as 'virtual' can be overridden.  Methods marked as 'abstract' are not necessarily overridden, they are implemented in classes that implement the abstract class.  They can be marked as virtual in the implementation.  There is no limit to the number of times a virtual method can be overridden.

Do you need an answer for VB.NET?

Comment: No, you can't choose to implement an abstract method as virtual or non-virtual. All abstract methods are automatically virtual.

Comment: Can abstract methods contain implementation or not?

Comment: abstract method cannot have implementations.. read this http://www.dotnetperls.com/abstract

Comment: An abstract method is automatically virtual. The abstract method (or property) does not have a method body (accessor body) but just specifies a semicolon (`;`). In the class that derives from the abstract class, when the abstract method of the base class is to be implemented, the `override` keyword is used (even when the base method had no implementation).

Comment: @RKh in an abstract class there can be methods that are implemted.  but the abstract methods themselves cannot have implementations.  that's a better use case to use a virtual method